# Двусмысленный перевод опции Skip в очереди проверок

Tags: дефект, статус-отклонено, локализация, очередь-проверок

Сейчас переведено как **Пропустить**. Подразумевается значение `не совершить какое-либо действие из ряда подобных`.
Но у этого слова есть и другое значение - `позволить кому-либо, чему-либо пройти мимо, сквозь или через себя`, пересекающееся с значением соседней кнопки **Ничего делать не нужно**
https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C

**UPDATE:** Для вахтёров в моём общежитии "пропустить" и "ничего делать не нужно" означало одно и то же

Comment: Что-то нет никакой реакции.

Answer (score 5):

**Оставить перевод "Пропустить"**

"Skip" в очереди проверок  означает "я не хочу принимать решение касательно проверки этого ответа, покажите следующий". Так что всё в порядке, перевод нормальный.  Для случая когда просто ничего не нужно делать есть одноименная кнопка в очереди проверки новых сообщений.

Когда вы нажимаете "Пропустить", система не засчитывает вам выполненную проверку и не убирает вопрос из очереди.

Comment: Это я понимаю. Но если представить процедуру проверки сообщений как работу охранника, впускающего или не впускающего людей в здание, то смысл этих двух опций становится трудноразличим

Comment: @php5engineer: работа охранника очень чётко устроена: он всегда принимает решение явным образом: пропустить или не пропустить. Кнопка "Пропустить" означает "я не буду принимать решение по этому вопросу, умываю руки". Для охранника это означает "отправить на другой пропускной пункт или позвать коллегу, чтобы тот принимал решение".

Comment: Я имею ввиду другой вид охранников. Для вахтёров в моём общежитии "пропустить" и "ничего делать не нужно" означало одно и то же

Comment: @php5engineer: ладно, тогда уточните, что вы предлагаете сделать?

Comment: Придумать другой вариант перевода :)

Comment: @php5engineer: предлагайте варианты )

Answer (score 2):

Вариант перевода: **К следующему**

Однозначно дает понять, что проверяющий переходит к следующему вопросу, а с этим ничего не будет делать.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант перевода: **Умываю руки**

Для любителей мифологии и фразеологизмов.

Comment: "Ой-ой! А вдруг мой аккаунт удалится!" :D